# django oscar: How to send an email to store admin for order placement notification

Tags: django, django-oscar

I want to get a notification

> email

to myself (As Admin) when there is new order placed on my django-oscar store.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way that I am following to send emails to the admins, what I did was forked the order app and the went to the utils.py, went to the place_order function under OrderCreator() class, oscar sends signals for order placement the code from oscar's github is [here](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/84a18eeac4c63a87bdad67df834513f82a335ea4/src/oscar/apps/order/utils.py#L97), so what I did was put my send email code after this.
SO I created a communication event type with code ADMIN_ORDER_MAIL in my admin side and used that here to send mails.

My code is here:

```
# Send an email to admin on placing of order
        ctx = {'order': order, 'user': order.user}
        commtype_code = 'ADMIN_ORDER_MAIL'
        try:
            event_type = CommunicationEventType.objects.get(code=commtype_code)
            # print("Event type typr: ", type(event_type))
            # self.create_communication_event(order, event_type)

        except Exception as e:
            messages = CommunicationEventType.objects.get_and_render(code=commtype_code, context=ctx)
            # print(e)
        else:
            messages = event_type.get_messages(ctx)

            send_mail(
                subject=messages['subject'],
                message='',
                html_message=messages['html'],
                from_email='from email address',
                recipient_list=['to email address'],
                fail_silently=False,
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use [django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/signals/).

Django-Oscar has some signals defined for multiple actions, and one of them is associated to the action of [order placed.](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.1/ref/signals.html#order-placed)

This signal provide information about the order made and the user who made the order. You can use this information to send the email.

I hope it will be useful for you!