# Django Oscar - email admin on order placed

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I am trying to get django-oscar to send me an email everytime an order is placed. It sounds simple but I am struggling.

I have tried a couple of methods but all failed...

Is there an easy way?

Comment: You may have better luck of getting a quick answer if you provide a few of those ways that you've attempted and why they failed rather than requesting the solution to a relatively open ended question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set up a listener for the [`order_placed`](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/ref/signals.html#order-placed) signal, and then do whatever actions you want there.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver

from oscar.apps.order.signals import order_placed

@receiver(order_placed)
def send_merchant_notification(sender, order, user, **kwargs):
    # Do stuff here
```

Alternatively, fork the `orders` app and override the `OrderCreator` class to inject additional logic when an order is placed.

Comment: For the alternative method specified in this answer you can take a look to this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089210/django-oscar-how-to-send-an-email-to-store-admin-for-order-placement-notificati/54586517#54586517) on how to implement it.

Comment: Wow! all I had to do was to put that code into signals.py in orders app and write emailmessage and now I am getting the email when orders are received. Thank you!